# How can I forward specific emails to my server if I set my MX records to connect with Gmail Business?

Tags: email, meteor, gmail, gmail-api, incoming-mail

I am using Gmail for business and have set the MX records for my domain to point to gmail.

I've been searching but can't find anything in regards to gmail api webhooks for posting specific emails to a specific URL route on my server.

I need to do something similar to this: https://sendgrid.com/blog/receive-inbound-email-meteorjs/ but instead of using sendgrid, I need to do it with gmail api since my MX records are pointing to Gmail.

Is this even possible with gmail api? If so can you point me in the right direction.

Basically any email sent to x@mydomain.com need to be posted to the route mydomain.com/incoming-email. Need to be able to do this with Gmail.

Comment: You may check this [Configuring Your MX Records: Other domain hosts](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33915?hl=en) support page. You need to enable advanced settings to edit your MX records. MX records may be located in DNS Management, Mail Server Configuration, or Name Server Management. Then check this [page](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3251241?hl=en) to set up email forwarding. Be noted that when you set up email forwarding, Google Domains creates MX resource records.

Comment: @abielita Your comment does not seem to answer my question. I do NOT need to setup email forwarding. And as I stated I have already setup the MX records correctly. I am looking for a way Gmail can send post request to my server whenever an email is to x@mydomain.com.